# Get selected li value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get dropdown item which coming using script.How can i get "data dial code" in jquery.
In console html showing like this

```
<li class="country" data-dial-code="93" data-country-code="af"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag af"></div></div><span class="country-name">Afghanistan (&#8235;افغانستان&#8236;&lrm;)</span><span class="dial-code">+93</span></li>

<li class="country" data-dial-code="355" data-country-code="al"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag al"></div></div><span class="country-name">Albania (Shqipëri)</span><span class="dial-code">+355</span></li>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant script?

Comment: @Ritu - you need to read up about jQuery selectors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected `li` value in `jquery` like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li.country').each(function(index, elem){
  var allDialCode = $(elem).find('.dial-code').text();
   console.log(allDialCode);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="country" data-dial-code="93" data-country-code="af"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag af"></div></div><span class="country-name">Afghanistan (&#8235;افغانستان&#8236;&lrm;)</span><span class="dial-code">+93</span></li>

<li class="country" data-dial-code="355" data-country-code="al"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag al"></div></div><span class="country-name">Albania (Shqipëri)</span><span class="dial-code">+355</span></li>
```

Now all values in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for your selected li

```
$('.country').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Then when you want to get data-dial-code of selected li you can do:

```
console.log($('.country.selected').data('dial-code'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(e) 
{ 
  alert($(this).attr('data-dial-code'));
});
```